# Javascript utf-8 substr and length function

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I am trying to do a substr on a UTF-8 string like हिन्दी.

The problem is that it becomes totally screwed up=> with some weird box in the end (does not show here, although i copy pasted) (its something like [00 02]): हिन...

okay this is how it appers after using substr function:

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/765/capturexv.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/765/capturexv.png)

Wondering if there is some function to solve this problem? *Atleast I want to remove that funny box.*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Which unicode plane do these characters come from? Perhaps you're splitting a surrogate pair...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript encodes strings with UTF-16, meaning characters outside the basic multilingual plane have to be represented as a surrogate pair. Splitting a string in the middle of such a pair might explain your results.

As I understand the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2#Encoding_of_characters_outside_the_BMP), you'll have to check if your last character lies in the range 0xD800–0xDBFF and, if so, either drop it or add the following character (which should be in range 0xDC00-0xDFFF) to the substring.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the box is the font's representation of the UTF-8 values that the substring created. Try to remove the character at the box's position and it should be removed.

Comment: But I dont know if the box will appear everytime or not. I cant just randomly remove the last character. The text will eventually be dynamic.

Comment: Try a font that is compatible with the language you are coding for? It should display the right representation every time then. Most special languages use a specific kind of fonts, try googling for the "language font utf-8" or something similar.

Comment: @Zolomon, thats not correct, cause you can see that the first few letters of the word are displaying correctly. and only after substr the box comes.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding to put UTF-8 byte sequences into JavaScript string objects. Instead, rely on the Unicode support of JavaScript, and use a proper Unicode string (instead of an UTF-8 string).

My guess is that you managed to slice the string in the middle of a character, so that the result is an incomplete character. Browser then try to render it anyway, leading to moji-bake.

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by Unicode support of Javascript? Proper unicode string?